# how to send SMS in Hindi using php through my website

Tags: php

I have tried php encode, uriencode but it showing ?????? in SMS on mobilesms_text = 'Hindi - हिंदी , Chinese - 痴呢色 ，Russian - руссиан';

```
 $encoded_text = utf8_encode($sms_text);
 $message = urlencode($encoded_text);

$infor='महोदय आपका सिंहस्थ २०१६ के लिए भूमि आवंटन  का आवेदन स्वीकार करते हुए    सिंहस्थ xxxx के लिए  भूमि आवंटित का दी गई है';
$encoded_text = $sms_msg = mb_convert_encoding($infor, "UTF-8", "auto");
$infor=urlencode($encoded_text);
    $data = array(
       "username" => "xxxxST",    



       "password" => "xxxjx",              

       "senderid" =>"SxAST",                

       "smsservicetype" =>"singlemsg",        



       "mobileno" =>"94xxxxx5098",               



       "content"  => $matter." "."Simhasth 2016- Ujjain: Land allotment form have been accepted and required land alloted to you. Contact Simhasth mela karayalya-Ujjain"
```

Comment: I believe the encoding that you're looking for is UCS2. Trye `$message = mb_convert_encoding($encoded_text, 'UCS-2', 'UTF-8')`

Comment: i tried it but it is not working. please read my question again i added my code into it now.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a blog for this i m sure it will help others as i m too late for answering this.

[Click Here](http://www.vivekmoyal.in/send-sms-in-hindi-using-api/)

```
$str="98XXXXXXXX  100 रु का रीचार्ज किया गया है|"; // Our SMS
$msg=str_replace('%u', '',$smsClass->utf8_to_unicode($str));//it will convert the normal message to the unicode

public function utf8_to_unicode($str) {
$unicode = array();
$values = array();
$lookingFor = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    $thisValue = ord($str[$i]);
    if ($thisValue < 128) {
        $number = dechex($thisValue);
        $unicode[] = (strlen($number) == 1) ? '%u000' . $number : "%u00" . $number;
    } else {
        if (count($values) == 0)
            $lookingFor = ( $thisValue < 224 ) ? 2 : 3;
        $values[] = $thisValue;
        if (count($values) == $lookingFor) {
            $number = ( $lookingFor == 3 ) ?
                    ( ( $values[0] % 16 ) * 4096 ) + ( ( $values[1] % 64 ) * 64 ) + ( $values[2] % 64 ) :
                    ( ( $values[0] % 32 ) * 64 ) + ( $values[1] % 64
                    );
            $number = dechex($number);
            $unicode[] =
                    (strlen($number) == 3) ? "%u0" . $number : "%u" . $number;
            $values = array();
            $lookingFor = 1;
        } // if
    } // if
}
return implode("", $unicode);
}
```

Comment: *"as i m too late for answering this."* No, you're not too late. Please add text from your blog post and reference it in the answer. Links tend to decay and die over time.